# Two Column Article content Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

How to make some of article when I click readmore the paragraph not show
to the bottom but to the right side...

Here's the illustration screenshot:

http://www.oymo.com/upload/uploads/collumn-artikel.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You can't do proper columns - ie. when the text flows from the bottom of one column it moves to the top of the next, without use of CSS3 (which isn't widely supported). You could probably do something with a bit of mootools or jquery as an alternative.

However, if you just want to show the intro text in one div and the main text in another (something like http://www.kodaklens.co.uk/mobile/) then you need to modify your template /templates/templatename/html/com_content/article/default.php, by creating your required 'static' layout and then loading the different article pieces into each container, but this won't help with text flow.